# SVM: Relation between VC dimension and number of kernel dimensions

Tags: kernel, classification, svm, dimension, training-data

I am exploring the SVM topic using SVM-light by Thorsten Joachims.

Now according to some introduction papers:

"The VC-dimension of the set of oriented hyperplanes in R<sup>n</sup> is n+1 [...]"

"When C = inf, the optimal hyperplane will be the one that completely separates
the data (assuming one exists) [...]"

I have prepared a two-dimensional linearly separable dataset and wanted to see the 2d hard-margin classifier, that we know from so many illustrations.

So I chose the following parameters:

- polynomial Kernel (a*b+c)<sup>d</sup> with d = 2
- C = 999 (so as to approach inf)

I get 3 support vectors, which is fine, but the estimated VC-dimension is more than 10,000.

Now I wonder if it is possible to have such high VCdim if the kernel is only two dimensional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be confusing few things here:

1. Polynomial kernel is **not** a "2 dimensional kernel", polynomial kernel maps to the roughly O(m<sup>d</sup>) dimensional space
2. Empirical VC dimension is **not** a true VC dimension, the true VC dimension is the analytical object, that cannot be directly computed "from the data", it requires rigorous proofs, and one (of a few existing) says that for n-dimensional space, VC dimension of the linear classifiers is n+1, it holds no matter how you "get" to this space.
3. Number of support vectors is somehow related to the generalization abilities of the model, and so is VC dimension. Unfortunately there is no easy "one-to-one" dependency between the number of support vectors and the VC dimension of the data. In fact, as far as I know, there is no known proof of the VC dimension of the SVM model (we know, that it is a gap tolerant classifier, which **should** have lower VC dimension, but it is far from being a dimension proof).

Comment: >"In fact, as far as i know, there is no known proof of the VC dimension of the SVM model" As far as I know, it depends on the kernel you are using. I remember had read before a proof that RBF kernel have infinite VC dimension and there was an example with the sin kernel that  was infinite too. But you are right, I don't think there is a general (kernel-independent) proof for the VC Dimension

Comment: Infinite dimension of the RBF kernel is obvious. I was refering to the actual VC dimension in the linear case, one can take the margin-based approximation min{ D^2/M^2, d+1 }, where D is the bounding sphere size and M is the margin. Yet neither of them is the parameter of the SVM itself.

Comment: The VC dimension for a linear SVC? Well the linear case is just a linear classifier and the maximum dataset size that a linear classifier can shatters is 3 for the general case. If you add the non linear dependency restriction then it would be n+1 for R^n. I might just misunderstood again what you were referring to.

Comment: I suggest you read a bit about the gap tolerant classifiers, this is much more complex case. And this is not the place for such a discussion.

Comment: I believe we are talking about two different things, you are talking about an empirical estimation (which is the context where the gap tolerant concept would come into the discussion) and I am talking about the theoretical VC dimension for the general algorithm. In any case, I am agreed with you that this doesn't seem to be the proper place to hold this (interesting) discussion.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just wanted to make sure that there is no contradiction in the information I have.

Comment: Now allow me two more questions: (1) Assuming I could choose to use no kernel at all, and have the 2d linearly separable data, then the VC-dimension would be 3? (2) Is it the fact that the polynomial kernel causes the decision boundary to be no longer a hyperplane which allows so many points to be shattered? (as seen in the extreme case in 2d for the sinus line)

Comment: (1) Yes, it would be 3 (2) No and yes. It will still be hyperplane, but no longer in 2dimensional space, but in the feature space, which in case of d=2 has quadraticaly more dimensions. If you project the decision boundary to the input space than it will obviously no longer be a line so also not a hyperplane (but it is just an illusion caused by looking at the part of the true surface)

Answer (score 1):

The VC dimension doesn't map to the amount of SVs of a given solution.

The VC dimension is the maximum number of dataset samples that can be shattered perfectly by the model for any combination of the labels associate with those points. On the other hand, support vectors are the points that define the hyperplane.

EDIT:

I am extending a bit my answer based on your comment.

First, when you say this:

> "When C = inf, the optimal hyperplane will be the one that completely separates the data (assuming one exists) [...]"

That doesn't mean that there is a direct relation between C and the VC dimension (as you suggested when you say that C=999 would produce a VC-dimension of 10000). What that does mean is with C = inf you would enforce all constraints and hence producing hard margin model (an hyperplane that separates completely the data)

> "whether the fact that the VC-dimension of the set of oriented hyperplanes in R^n is n+1 still holds when applying a polynomial kernel that maps into 2 dimensions"

That would be true in the feature space, but keep in mind that the decision boundary in input space won't be an hyperplane anymore, in fact would be non-linear.

> "polynomial Kernel (a*b+c)^d with d = 2" ... " if the kernel is only two dimensional?"

That kernel is not bidimesional, it would map differently depending on the other parameters.

Comment: The question is whether the fact that the VC-dimension of the set of oriented hyperplanes in R^n is n+1 still holds when applying a polynomial kernel that maps into 2 dimensions. Unfortunately I cannot select to use no kernel.

Comment: @user1850980 Sorry for the confusion, that's not what I understood from your question. I would like to make some point out some points but this  space is too short so I will edit my answer